# Fill NaN values using dictionary pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, apply

I have a dataframe `dfp` with columns `Brand_ID` and `Brand_Name` (and some more columns like `Product_ID`, `Product_Name` etc.)

Some Brand names are NaN because of multiple brand_IDs separated by comma (see picture)
[image]

I want to fill those NaNs with the actual brand names separated by comma.
I have a reference dictionary that I can use for this
[image]

Comment: What if one line in `dfp` has two Brand_Ids, that can be found in `x`? Say for instance that IDs 8457 and 17831 are keys in x, what do you do?

Comment: What type of data is Brand_ID? string?

Comment: @Riley, yes, Brand_ID is string

Comment: @BeChillerToo, if one row in Brand_ID has two Brand_IDs, it returns null value in Brand_Name. It gives correct Brand_Name only if there is one Brand_ID

Comment: Oh ok, then I guess you could transform your dictionary to a dataframe then join (or merge depending on your indexes) your two dataframes

Answer (score 0):

For rows with missing values, use a lambda function to split values, match in dictionary, and join:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Brand_ID': ['11,12,15','10','15,11'],
                   'Brand_Name': [np.nan, 'aaa', np.nan]})


x = {'11': 'ww', '12': 'oup', '15': 'ret'}
m = df['Brand_Name'].isna()
f = lambda y: ','.join(x[z] for z in y.split(',') if z in x)
df.loc[m, 'Brand_Name'] = df.loc[m, 'Brand_ID'].apply(f)

print(df)
   Brand_ID  Brand_Name
0  11,12,15  ww,oup,ret
1        10         aaa
2     15,11      ret,ww
```